MDX file is not parsed properly in content-layer + nextjs?
I started using content layer for my side project and I'm struggling to solve that issue of parsing my mdx files correctly.
I have this content structure
|-content
         |---chapters
                    |----chapter-01.mdx
                    |----chapter-02.mdx
         |
         |---introduction.mdx


chapter-01.mdx
-------
title: Chapter 01
type: Chapter
date: 2021-12-24
---

# Chapter 01

import { Button } from "@/components/ui/button.tsx"

<Button >Click</Button>


Contentlayer.config.ts

import { defineDocumentType, makeSource } from "contentlayer/source-files"
import remarkGfm from "remark-gfm"

export const Chapter = defineDocumentType(() => ({
  name: "Chapter",
  filePathPattern: `chapters/**/*.mdx`,
  contentType: "mdx",
  fields: {
    title: { type: "string", required: true },
    date: { type: "date", required: true },
  },
  computedFields: {
    url: {
      type: "string",
      resolve: (chapter) => {
        return `/chapters/${chapter._raw.flattenedPath.split("/").pop()}`
      },
    },
  },
}))

export const Introduction = defineDocumentType(() => ({
  name: "Introduction",
  filePathPattern: `**/*.mdx`,
  contentType: "mdx",
  fields: {
    title: { type: "string", required: true },
    date: { type: "date", required: true },
  },
  computedFields: {
    url: {
      type: "string",
      resolve: (introduction) => {
        console.log(introduction._raw.flattenedPath) // Debugging
        return `/introduction/${introduction._raw.flattenedPath
          .split("/")
          .pop()}`
      },
    },
  },
}))

export default makeSource({
  contentDirPath: "content",
  documentTypes: [Chapter, Introduction],
  mdx: {
    remarkPlugins: [remarkGfm],
  },
})


Pages structrures

Chapter page

import { allChapters } from 'contentlayer/generated';
import { useMDXComponent } from 'next-contentlayer/hooks';
import { notFound } from 'next/navigation';

export async function generateStaticParams() {
  return allChapters.map((chapter) => ({
    slug: chapter._raw.flattenedPath.split("/").pop(),
  }));
}

const getChapter = (slug: string) => {
  return allChapters.find((chapter) => chapter._raw.flattenedPath.split("/").pop() === slug);
};

const ChapterPage = async ({ params }: { params: { slug: string } }) => {
  const chapter = getChapter(params.slug);
  if (!chapter) notFound();

  const Component = useMDXComponent(chapter.body.code);
  
  return (
    <div>
      <Component />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChapterPage;


Current

Expected
I expect the title Chapter 01 to be bold and large because it starts with #.
